# Type conversion from T to string and from string to T, where T is known to be string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have

```
public bool AddParameter<T>(string pattern, SqlDbType parameterType, int length, T value)
{
}
```

and I need a special case for strings, which should be truncated (MS doesn't do this to me, I don't know what they need the length for in the first hand). So I tried to query whether T is string, with my final result

```
if(value is string) {
}
```

awaiting some testing. Now I need to do some type conversion to do string functions on `value`, because

```
 value = value.Substring(0,length);
```

does not work. So I tried around:

```
value = (T)(((string)value).Substring(0,length));
```

but a conversion from T to string is not possible. I guessed value.ToString() would yield the same result, so I tried again:

```
 value = (T)((value.ToString()).Substring(0,length);
```

but also a conversion from string to T is not possible. Could someone help me out of the maze?

Comment: Do you really want to provide an `AddParameter<T>` method that _modifies_ the parameter? These   things are very easily forgotten.

Comment: Yes, I want. But I added the following very important line in my code: `dbg.Warn("Truncated "+pattern+" to "+length+" characters.");`. Deployed code is more maintainable when half the lines are only for debug purposes. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double cast should do the trick

```
 value = (T)(object)(value.ToString().Substring(0,length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use generics if T is known to be string ? You have to add an overload that accepts string, do your logic in there and pass the result to generic AddParameter:

```
public bool AddParameter(string pattern, SqlDbType parameterType, int length, string value)
{
    //do your stuff
    return AddParameter<string>(pattern, parameterType, length, updatedValue);
}

public bool AddParameter<T>(string pattern, SqlDbType parameterType, int length, T value)
{
}
```

Comment: How does C# know whether I want to use the one method or the other? I mean, `string` also matches `T`? So there are two methods which could be meant...

Comment: And I should add that `AddParameter<T>` is also called from `AddParameters<T>.` Would `AddParameters<T>` also manage to call `AddParameter` instead of `AddParameter<T>`, or would I have to duplicate that function?

Comment: You can check if parameter type is string in AddParameters and choose the right method, e.g. `if(value is string) AddParameter(value.ToString()); else AddParameter(value);`